# Where can I find/set the expected keysize in cert-manager?

Tags: ssl, x509certificate2, cert-manager

I am following these instructions

https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/nginx-ingress/#step-7-deploy-a-tls-ingress-resource

When I try to check for the certificate, however, I am getting the following error in cert-manager

```
kubectl describe certificate -n sandbox ca-key-pair
```

```
Warning  DecodeFailed  54m   cert-manager-certificates-key-manager  Existing private key in Secret "ca-key-pair" does not match requirements on Certificate resource, mismatching fields: [spec.keySize]
```

None of the yamls that I have deployed (specified in the tutorial) has [spec.keySize]  Where is this value set?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer because I do not know where to find the keySize metric, but I was able to fix the problem by reissuing the keys.

I hope this is able to help someone else in the future.